# How to achieve pipeline parallelism in TBB flow graph

Tags: c++, tbb, tbb-flow-graph

I am working on an image processing application which is built with tbb::flow_graph.
The input comes from a video file or a camera.
Each image processing node is wrapped in a multifunction_node (I need the multifunction_node's ability to selectively stop propagating graph messages).
Currently I am using graph.wait_for_all() after feeding each input frame into the root node, but I would like to be able to take advantage of pipeline parallelism.
I.e. if node A is connected to node B, I would like to let node A start working on its next input after it is done producing its output, instead of waiting for B to finish.

Could you please provide cues for how to do this efficiently and idiomatically?
I am new to TBB and I feel that I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: Please add some code to show what exactly you have tried.

Comment: The TBB documentation has examples of flow graphs that use pipeline parallelism, e.g. here: https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/Data_Flow_Graph.html